# How can i Animate cell of fixed data table component?

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup, fixed-data-table

I'm using facebooks fixedDataTable to show stock dashboard. what i need to achieve is flash fixed data table cell (say price column) green or red based on the change of price. How do we achieve animation inside fixed data table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with css in the children components of the datatable `<Cell>`. Something like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // if the price has changed, add a class to do some animation stuff
  if (nextProps.price != this.props.price) {
    this.setState( className: "fancy-flash-class-in" );
  }
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  // after the component has updated, set the class back
  if (this.state.className == "fancy-flash-class-in") {
    setTimeout(() = > this.setState(
      {className: "fancy-flash-class-out"}),
    500);
  }
}
```

`componentDidUpdate()` is called really fast, so you will do a `setTimeout`, otherwise the animation won't work.

In css, you can add animations:

- fancy-flash-class-in: give the component a highlight-color, and a css transition
- fancy-flash-class-out: the basic component color, with css animation to go back from red or green to basic color

So in your css file:

```
.fancy-flash-class-out {
  background-color: grey;
  transition: background-color 2s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s; /* Safari */
}
```

Simple demo [codepen here](https://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/wWwepQ?editors=0010)

Comment: No, this is not working. if i comment the this.setState inside componentDidUpdate() , i can see cell transition from basic color to red and remain in that red color. it seems that componentDidUpdate is being called so fast after the componentWillReceiveProps that i cant see the change of background color.

Comment: This depends on your css settings. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what is happening is 1)componentWillReceiveProps is called and "fancy-flash-class-in" class is set. (render is called) 2) even before this transition is complete componentDidUpdate is called setting the state back to "fancy-flash-class-out"  (render called again) . so the final affect is i always see grey.

Comment: instead of delay in transition, i have added a delay (setTimeout) inside componentDidUpdate when calling  "this.setState " . This seems to work, but when the update frequency is not constant, animation is not smooth at all. I will give a try to "CSSTransitionGroup"

Comment: Yeah timeout on setState would work too. But I prefer the pure CSS solution. Is more conforming to react state (theoretically, your component could be unmounted after timeout, and things would break down). CSStransitiongroup is more for components moving in and out, which looks different from your "animate on state change" needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112956/discussion-between-user1803361-and-wintvelt).